# Strava API oAuth Process Token Exchange page can't be reached

Tags: php, json, curl, token, strava

While I am able to receive the initial Strava oAuth Code through the authorize? process on the Strava page, I am struggling with the token exchange process described here: https://developers.strava.com/docs/authentication/

Code below does only result in

```
Sorry, this one stays red.
The page you’re looking for doesn’t exist, but you’re not at a dead end. 
Here are a few options:

Be sure you have the right url and try again
Sign up or log in at strava.com
See what the community’s been up to at Strava Stories
Search for a particular activity or club
Get a little help from Strava Support
```

I am quite new to the Strava API, but also directly pasting the resulting URL in the browser does result in the same page response.

```
$url = "https://www.strava.com/oauth/token?client_id=XXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&code=".$code."&grant_type=authorization_code";

echo "<br />".$url;

$cURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Accept: application/json'
));

$result = curl_exec($cURL);

curl_close($cURL);



print_r($result);

?>
```

Thanks in Advance for your support on this matter !

Comment: Looking at the docs, this is supposed to be a POST, but you're performing a GET. Use `curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, true);`

Comment: Well, yes. It was a simple as this. I am ready to kill myself. Thanks for your time and putting and end to my frustrations !

Comment: Glad to help! We've all been there :)

Comment: @Marc - Would you be willing to update your original post with working HTTP POST and or snippet? That would greatly help me as I am in the same boat as you with trying to get auth working

Comment: @Bryce - absolutely ! Shared the correct code. Now I am struggling at returning the output to $result, but too early to give up on this ;) Happy to collaborate on this matter !

Answer (score 0):

@Chris White solved it, was using POST instead of GET. Thanks for the help

```
echo "<br />".$url;

$cURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Accept: application/json'
));

$result = curl_exec($cURL);

curl_close($cURL);



print_r($result);

?>
```